# Bloquear link em .php

Tags: php

Bom, estava fazendo alguns teste no upload de imagem no meu site e o que me deparei foi o seguinte, ao o usuário botar um link como "*.php*", "*.js*", "*.html*" ele poderá facilmente fazer um *iplogger* com isto, quero bloquear os links com "*.php*", etc... só quero permitir *.gif*, *.png* e *.jpg*

**Segue o coódigo:**

```
<input type="text" name="img" class="listcc" placeholder="URL DA IMAGEM"/><br/><br/><br/>

$img = trim($_POST["img"]);

if ($img != null) {
  mysql_query("UPDATE usuarios SET img='$img' WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
  echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Imagem de perfil atualizada com sucesso');</script>";

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você poderá utilizar `regex` para verificar a `URL`.

```
if ( preg_match("/\.(?:gif|png|jpe?g)(?:\?.*)?$/", $img) ) {
    die("É uma imagem válida. Pode atualizar no seu banco de dados");
} else {
    die("Ops! Não me parece ser uma imagem.");
}
```

**Explicação do Regex:**

```
\.(?:gif|png|jpe?g)(?:\?.*)?$
└───────┬────────┘ └──┬──┘ └┬┘
        │             │     └─── Captura a última ocorrência
        │             └───────── Remove tudo que há após `?`
        └─────────────────────── Verifique a extensão é `gif`, `png`, `jpeg` ou `jpg`
```

Mas isso pode não ser suficiente. Se você verificar `https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a95dfb4f780323740a8ce56633a184ed?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG` é uma imagem válida (está em `.png`), mas ela seria ignorada, já que não possui a extensão na *URL*.

Nesse caso, basta enviar uma requisição e capturar o retorno do `content-type`, por exemplo:

```
<?php

$url = 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a95dfb4f780323740a8ce56633a184ed?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG';

ob_start();
/* Instancia o curl */
$ch = curl_init($url);

/* Informa que deseja seguir os redirecionamento */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

/* Desabilita a verificação do SSL */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

/* Executaa requisição */
curl_exec($ch);

/* Captura o Content-Type retornado */
$i = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);

/* Fecha a coenxão */
curl_close($ch);
ob_end_clean();


/* Define os mimetypes permitidos */
$mimeAllowed = [
    'image/png',
    'image/jpeg',
    'image/gif',
];

/* Verifica se o mimetype retornado, consta na variável acima. */
if (in_array($i, $mimeAllowed)) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE usuarios SET img='$url' WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
} else {
    die("Error");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

faz uma validação com regex no front-end e/ou no back-end, impossibilitando enviar arquivos com extensão diferente da desejada

No PHP:

```
preg_match("[a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]+\.(jpg|gif|png)", "exemplo/minha_imagem.png")
//Retorna TRUE se for válido ou FALSE se for inválido
```

No JS:

```
"exemplo/minha_imagem.png".match("[a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]+\.(jpg|gif|png)")
//Retorna TRUE se for válido ou FALSE se for inválido
```

No HTML:

```
pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]+\.(jpg|gif|png)"
```

Recomendo o uso tanto no back-end como no front-end, no front-end é melhor para o usuário já que não vai sair da página, também tornando mais rápida, porém no front-end a validação é facilmente burlada, por isso colocar no back-end também.

[regex](http://www.scriptcaseblog.com.br/regex/) = regular expression, em pt-br expressões regulares

Comment: Não poderia dar exemplo do codigo? pois não faço ideia do que seja este "Regexp"

Comment: Editei a resposta

Answer (score 1):

É importante verificar o mimetype do arquivo, pois existe um tipo de ataque em que vc envia um arquivo php com extensão jpg e consegue executa-lo no servidor. Por isso **NÃO BASTA** verificar a string do nome do arquivo conforme as outras respostas que colocaram aqui.

Para isto utilize a classe [finfo](http://php.net/manual/en/class.finfo.php).

```
<?php

$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
if ( array_search(
    $finfo->file($_FILES['teste']['tmp_name']),
    array(
        'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
        'png' => 'image/png',
        'gif' => 'image/gif',
    ), true) == true) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE usuarios SET img='$img' WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
    echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Imagem de perfil atualizada com sucesso');</script>";

}
```

No HTML é preciso modificar seu input type para **file**. Exemplo:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="file.php">
<input type="file" name="teste">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Fonte do trecho do código: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php